# Error in require('child_process') function not defined - TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, gulp

Getting error:

```
zone.js:260 Uncaught EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:8:48
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: ReferenceError: require is not defined
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at AppComponent.performCmdOperation (http://localhost:8000/app/app.component.js:43:67)
```

and 
**app.component.ts** is

```
export class AppComponent{

SelectType = EnumSelectType;
selectedSection: SelectType = EnumSelectType[EnumSelectType.Home];
selectPage(selectType:EnumSelectType) {
    console.log('Global : ' + EnumSelectType[selectType]);
    this.selectedSection = EnumSelectType[selectType];
    console.log(this.selectedSection + ' selected');
}

performCmdOperation(){
    console.log('in perform action');
    const exec = require('sdk/system/child_process').exec; //this is the point where I'm getting error.
    exec('ipconfig', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
            return;
        }
        console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
    });
}
```

Please help me finding the issue. Is there any `import missing or any dependency` required for using **'child_process'**.

My current dependencies are

```
"bootstrap": "^3.3.6",

"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.4",

"systemjs": "0.19.27",
"es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
"zone.js": "^0.6.12"
```

If this is something for which need to modify **gulpfile.ts**. Please instruct how 'child_process' will added in gulpfile.

Answer (score 4):

Try to require `child_process` instead, e.g.:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
```

To be honest, not sure what you're trying to achieve, since it looks like an Angular 2 project, which runs in a browser, but `child_process` is a built-in Node.js component, which would run on a server environment.

UPDATE:

In the context of a Gulp gulpfile, here's an example how one would use `child_process` to  call an external executable - in this case the dotnet CLI.

```
var ps = require("child_process");
gulp.task("serve:prod", function () {
    const dotnetPs = ps.exec("dotnet run");
    // redirect standard output of the child process to the console.
    dotnetPs.stdout.on("data", function(data) { console.log(data.toString()); });
    dotnetPs.stderr.on("data", function(data) { console.error(data.toString()); });
});
```

Comment: I'm using gulp for compiling this all, so if you can help me with gulp task function to use this within application that would help.

Comment: Same here, I'm using gulp for my build, and use `child_process` to call out to an external executable. I'll update my answer with an example. You wouldn't use this in an Angular 2 component, though.

Comment: Please provide the example with gulpfile.js task example if possible. Thanks!

Comment: @RAMWorld, the example is already in my updated answer. See the example after the "UPDATE: ". The example calls the `dotnet` executable, but you can replace it with whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use "" double quotes.You might try to run in CLI & have high possibility it is because quotes.